# Android wait for connection state

Tags: android, bluetooth, text-to-speech

My app needs to call TTS but first I want to try to connect to Bluetooth.  So i have a receiver trying to connect to Bluetooth. Since it takes a few seconds to return the connection state how do i wait until it has been connected?

Comment: Do you mean bluetooth headset?

Comment: Yes. Hoan, you're the man! I have implemented your BluetoothHeadsetUtils utility and works great.  I will get back to you if I run into a problem.  Thanks again!

Comment: I thought of a question for you Hoan.  How do I tell if there is a bluettooth device connected on app load?

Comment: onAudioConnected would be called.

Comment: Your class seems to work very well when connected to bluetooth prior to entering the app.  However I'm running into a problem with the tts coming through the BT headset when connecting while the app is already open.  isOnHeadsetSco says true but audio still comes through phone speaker.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at the link where you get the BluetoothHeadsetUtils. In that link I have a method to call TTS speak when using bluetooth headset.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a similar thing. I call my connect method, that runs on a separate thread. When that method finishes, it changes a Vvariable called "mState". So I've something like:

```js
while(mState != FINISHED){
  //Do Nothing
  }
```

WARNING! I can make this cause this code runs ON ANOTHER THREAD. If you do that on your main threat, your app will freeze.